# VSCODE: "Open Remote Repository" does not work

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with the Remote Repositories feature in Visual Studio Code and I can't seem to get it to work.

### Method 1:

- I open one of my repositories on the GitHub website and press `.` to open it in `github.dev`.
- I switch to the 'run and debug' tab, select 'Continue working on...' and select 'Reopen on the desktop'
- After allowing the action in Chrome, VSCode opens up with a message that the extension wants to open a URL
- I click 'Open' and then ... ... Nothing!! No notification, no progress bar, no error message, I even opened task manager and it didn't look like VSCode was doing anything.

### Method 2:

- I open a brand new VSCode window and select "Open Remote Repository" from the left sidebar.
- From the menu that appears, I select my GitHub account then select one of my repositories from the list.
- And then ... Nothing ... same as before.

Am I missing something?

I am running the latest version of Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

Comment: I can reproduce and it is most likely a bug in VSCode. I think you can open a bug report on VSCode's Github repository to let the team know.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the [GitHub Repositories](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.remotehub) extension. I had that extension on "pre-release" when I changed to release it works.

[image: pre-release]

Comment: mine is already on the release mode and still getting nothing! it should prompt me to github login page but nothing happening atm!

Comment: I just tried using "Open Remote Repository" again today and both methods seem to work now! I suspect I was automatically moved to the release version...